# android -How to make background like this

Tags: android, android-listview

I need to make background like this for each row on my listview .

[image]

Is there anyway to do it without using background images ? I mean is there anyway to make this by just using xml drawables ?

thanks

Comment: i don't think so. you will need to design this image in photoshop. And this image seems to be having texture also in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `repeatable` `Bitmap` and set it to your `layout` as a `background`.

Use this image [image]
(You can edit image if you want to change color etc , if you need psd file i can share)

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/rep_bg" 
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

in your `layout` set

```
android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"
```

Final output would be

Comment: it works very fine, only one question ,does the image size is important ?

Comment: no image size doesn't matter but keep image as small as you can.above image created by Photoshop just dedicated to this answer.:-)